# How do I change the shape (ie, add rounded corners) to a PreviewView?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-xml, androidx, android-camerax

I'm using AndroidX Camera in my app and have a simple PreviewView defined with a background that has rounded corners. For some reason, I can't figure out why when running the app, the PreviewView is still a perfect rectangle, I can't get the rounded corners to come out.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_inside_corners"/>
```

**rounded_inside_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/solid" />

</layer-list>
```

**solid.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

</shape>
```

**rounded.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the PreviewView not use back ground to display, it display on something surface view. You can try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2C2C2C"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's not a "background" issue but a "clip out line" problem

1.Need to set a round corner background just like you did

2.set clip out line to camera preview

```
ViewOutlineProvider provider = preview.getOutlineProvider();
    Outline outline = new Outline();
    outline.setRoundRect(left, top, right, bottom, radius);
    provider.getOutline(preview,outline);
    preview.setOutlineProvider(provider);
    preview.setClipToOutline(true);
```

It's work for me, not camera preivew, just a video player view (like surface view)

Comment: This is not working for me.